# How do i prove that $h$ is measurable where $h=fg$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M}),(Y,\Sigma)$ be a measurable spaces.

Let $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ and $g:Y\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be measurable functions.

Define $H(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$.

Then, how do i prove that $H:X\times Y\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is $\mathfrak{M}\otimes\Sigma$-measurable?

Comment: First check that this is true when $f$ and $g$ are indicator functions; then when they are simple functions; and then prove the general case.

Comment: their preimage of measurable set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\{\,(x,y)\mid H(x,y)>c\,\}=\bigcup_{a,b\in\mathbb Q_{>0}\atop ab>c}\{\,x\in X\mid f(x)>a\,\}\times \{\,y\in Y\mid g(y)>b\,\}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
You can prove it by using $fg=\frac{(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2}{4}$ and then show that $f+g$ and $f^2$ are measurable functions.